# Printing % from division in Python

Tags: python, string, format

I am using below to produce percentage:

```
L = ['aa', 'bb']

for row, each in enumerate(l):
    percent = float(row)/150 * 100
    print "{0:.0f}%".format(percent)
```

what I want is to have "0%" and "0.67%" respectively however it gives "0%" and "1%".

How can I correct it?

Comment: It should be `enumerate(L):` and use this print `{0:.2f}%".format(percent)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

> 'f' - Fixed point. Displays the number as a fixed-point number. The default precision is 6.
>
> ...
>
> The precision is a decimal number indicating how many digits should be displayed after the decimal point for a floating point value formatted with 'f' and 'F',..

So you can say how many digits you want after decimal points.

```
>>> "{0:.2f}%".format(123.4567)
'123.46%'
>>> 
>>> "{0:.5f}%".format(123.4567)
'123.45670%'
```

So change it to: `"{0:.2f}%".format(percent)` and also there is a typo in your for loop line, it should be `enumerate(L)`

```
L = ['aa', 'bb']

for row, each in enumerate(L):
    percent = float(row)/150 * 100
    print "{0:.2f}%".format(percent)
```

prints

```
0.00%
0.67%
```

Comment: thanks avi. I can't if yours comes earlier so I choose the above. Please let me know if it's not ok with you.

Comment: yup, I did post first but it's upto you to mark whichever you want (:

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell how much digits after decimal you wants.

```
for row, each in enumerate(L):
    percent = float(row)/150 * 100
    print "{0:.02f}%".format(percent)
```

output:-

```
0.00%
0.67%
```

at `print "{0:.02f}%".format(percent)`

ouput:-  `0.667%`